Can the matrix exponential $\frac{d}{dj} e^{H + j Q} |_{j=0}$ be written in terms of $e^{H}$ and $Q$?
Let $H$ and $Q$ be two skew-hermitian matrices (so $H^{\dagger} = -H$ and same for $Q$). Let $j$ be a real constant. Define the matrix:
$$
U(j)=e^{H+jQ} = \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (H + j Q)^n
$$
This question is about the related matrix
$$
U'(0) = \frac{d}{dj} U(j) \big|_{j=0} \ .
$$
question: Is it possible to write a closed form for $U'(0)$ in terms of $H$ and $Q$ and the matrix exponential map?
Notice that $\frac{d}{dj} (H + j Q)^1 \big|_{j=0} = Q$, and $\frac{d}{dj} (H + j Q)^2 \big|_{j=0} = HQ + QH$ and in general for $n \geq 2$:
$$
\frac{d}{dj}  (H + j Q)^n \big|_{j=0} = H^{n-1} Q + H^{n-2} Q H + \ldots HQH^{n-2} + Q H^{n-1} \ . 
$$
Using the definition of $U(j)$ it follows that
$$
U'(0) = Q + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{H^{n-1} Q + H^{n-2} Q H + \ldots HQH^{n-2} + Q H^{n-1}}{n!} \ .
$$
In the special case that $[H,Q]=0$ one finds the simple formula $U'(0) = e^{H}Q$. Does the formula simplify for the general case $[H,Q] \neq 0$?

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\rr{\LR{#1}}}
$Here is an interesting result for an arbitrary matrix $X=X(t)$ and analytic function $F=f(X)$
$$\eqalign{
f\LR{\mb{X&\dot X\\\hline0&X}} = \mb{F&\dot F\\\hline0&F} \\
}$$
For your particular problem $F=e^X\,$ and
$$\eqalign{
&X(t) = H+Qt \qiq \dot X(t) = Q = constant \\
}$$
All you need to do is evaluate the exponential of a block triangular matrix  and isolate the $(1,2)$ partition. This can be done for any value of $t,\,$ including $t=0.$

By defining matrix analogs of the $\lbrace e_k\in{\mathbb R}^2\rbrace$ basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
E_k &=e_k\k I \qiq E_1=\mb{I\\0},\q E_2 = \mb{0\\I} \\
}$$
the result can be succinctly written as
$$\eqalign{
\dot F &= E_1^T\,{\large f}\!\LR{E_1XE_1^T +E_2XE_2^T +E_1\dot XE_2^T}E_2 \\
}$$

You say "all you need to do is to evaluate the exponential of a block diagonal matrix." But this is just a different way of evaluating the same long sum you get by expanding $d(H+Qt)^n$. What am I missing here?

A power series is one of the least efficient / least accurate ways of evaluating the matrix exponential function.

Yes thats true. But if I write
$$\exp\left( \left[  \begin{array}{c|c} X & \dot X \ \hline  0  & X \end{array}\right] \right)$$
I still have to compute some power series. Maybe you could provide a simple example with some $2\times 2$ matrices.

$$U'(0)=\int_0^1e^{tH}Qe^{(1-t)H}dt.$$

@Letac_Gérard Thanks, How is this derived?

Simply expand $e^{tH}$ and  $e^{(1-t)H}$ and use the beta integral.
